# How to generate an xliff file for CaptionML

Tags: dynamics-nav

I'm creating a simple extension using the AL Visual Studio Code extension and I would like to get an xliff file so that I can translate my CaptionML.

How do I get that file?

This is my app.json

```
{
  "id": "ba7ba688-4dfe-4594-9870-2db44fec7321",
  "name": "test",
  "publisher": "Default publisher",
  "brief": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "privacyStatement": "",
  "EULA": "",
  "help": "",
  "url": "",
  "logo": "",
  "capabilities": [],
  "dependencies": [],
  "screenshots": [],
  "platform": "11.0.0.0",
  "application": "11.0.0.0",
  "idRange": {
    "from": 50100,
    "to": 50149
  }
}
```

and this is my extension code:

```
pageextension 50100 CustomerListExt extends "Customer List"
{
    layout {
        addafter(Name) {
            field(NameAgain;Name) {
                CaptionML = ENU = 'Another name field';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following property in your app.json:

```
"features": ["TranslationFile"]
```